# cURL, save only http response and url to the same file

Tags: shell, curl, sh

How to save url to a file and beside response from server?
I would like him to be in the file only address and answer from the server.
Example:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
curl -I http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges >> result.txt
```

In the output file now receives such a result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 105125
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 9d649d74-9d9b-4d89-aa1e-351eeb0ed03f
Set-Cookie: prov=bcbf7794-8fcd-4211-8322-a8df854c00ac;  
domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; 
path=/; HttpOnly Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 12:13:35 GMT
```

But I would like to receive in the output file such a result:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges -HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

What curl options I must have to use to get exactly this result?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are specific options inside curl to select headers fields, but scripting may help you

```
#!/bin/sh
url_0='http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges'
echo -n $url_0 -
curl -sI $url_0 | grep 'HTTP'
exit
```

Output:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges -HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```